# DataValue field value C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am doing  a project and can't make a Seletect Value from a list get the right value.A list is generated from a class UserDepartment,in this class I have this basically:

```
public class UserDepartment
{
    public long ID { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public User UserResponsible { get; set; }
}
```

The Problem is that I need a value from the class userResponsible,inside there is a value called EDV, I need this value but I don't know how to get.See this image below:

[image: List Generated]

If I use "   `ListBeneficiaryArea.DataValueField = "ID";`  ",I get the `ID` value normally,but i cant get the EDV value, I already tried  "`EDV`","`UserResponsible.EDV`" and "`UserResponsible`"but it didn't work.

There is other way for me to get the `UserResponsible`.`EDV` in the `DataValueField`?

After the change in DataSource i received this error:

[image]

Comment: What is `ListBeneficiaryArea`? I assume a `DropDownList`. You can always add the `ListItem`s programmaticall by using `list.Item.Add(new ListItem{ Text="Foo", Value="Bah" })`. Then it's an easy loop.

Comment: May be adding property `public int EDV{ get {return UserResponsible.EDV; } }` in `UserDepartment` and using it as `value` field

Comment: change `select new { ID, EDV = a.UserResponsible.EDV };` to `select new { Description, EDV = a.UserResponsible.EDV };`

Comment: Tks Mike Debela,worked perfect

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change your `DataSource` to the following:

```
ListBeneficiaryArea.DataSource = from a in lstBUAreas
                                 select new { ID, EDV = a.UserResponsible.EDV };
```

Then you can do:

```
ListBeneficiaryArea.DataTextField = "ID";
ListBeneficiaryArea.DataValueField = "EDV";
```